# Getting app.use require middleware even though I followed the documentation

Tags: node.js

I am getting app.use() requires a middleware function error when using Express edge package in npm. I am using this - https://github.com/ecrmnn/express-edge

I followed and read the documentation but I can't seem to find what else does the function require

Here is the code.

```
const path = require('path');
const expressEdge = require('express-edge');
const express = require('express');




const app = new express()

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(expressEdge);
app.set('views', `${__dirname}/views`);



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.reso0lve(__dirname, 'pages/about.html'))
})

app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/post.html'))
})

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/contact.html'))
})


app.listen( 4000, () => {
    console.log('App has started')
})
```

Here is the error:

```
E:\NODE-JS-BLOG\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
    ^

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (E:\NODE-JS-BLOG\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\NODE-JS-BLOG\index.js:11:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
app.use() requires a middleware function[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `expressEdge.engine` ?

```
const path = require('path');
const {engine} = require('express-edge');
const express = require('express');

const app = new express()

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(engine);
app.set('views', `${__dirname}/views`);
```